# PHP cron script for insert and update xml data

Tags: php, drupal, cron

I want to write an php script for cron job in which xml data is parsed and insert into DB , at first time  may be only insert query is fire but from next time same data will come or may be new data also comes so in that condition what logic to be implemented to insert new data

Comment: You don't insert, but you Update. You need to find something unique in the data, like a Id or something to identify it and may do a update in database.

Comment: You could also INSERT on duplicate UPDATE.

Comment: Do you want to use simpleXML or DOMDocument?

Comment: i am using simpleXML with on duplicate UPDATE but it doesn't work on Auto increments columns so i create unique column  and its work fine thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

At your import script at start first add drupal's bootstrap code, which is:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

After that you can use drupal normally, i.e. you can use `node_load()`, `node_save()` and so on..

Then save your file somewhere and set cron to call it. I'm talking about server cron here, not drupal's cron.

For storing content in database I suggest you to create custom content type, and add all the data you need (get from XML). Use drupal's standard api `node_save()` and `node_load()`, to store/get stored content. For querying database use drupal's "views" module.